# Evernote Android_JOB onRunJob() method is never called

Tags: android, android-studio, job-scheduling, android-job

I have implemented Evernote Android Job in my android application through

```
implementation 'com.evernote:android-job:1.2.6'
```

And I have define as signleton to get instance I have initiated it in my Application class through

```
 JobManager.create(this).addJobCreator(new CreatingJob());
```

And I have two classes which are
**JOB CREATING CLASS**

```
  public class CreatingJob implements JobCreator {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Job create(@NonNull String tag) {
        switch (tag) {
            case SyncMasterDataJOB.TAG:
                return new SyncMasterDataJOB();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**JOB CLASS**

```
    public class SyncMasterDataJOB extends Job  {
    public static final String TAG = "job_note_sync";


    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected Result onRunJob(@NonNull Params params) {
        //Doing my Task HERE
        MyLog.ShowELog("JOB STARTED", "Job Has been Started");
        MyToast.Lmsg(getContext(), "Job Has been Started");
        return Result.SUCCESS;
    }


    public static void scheduleJob() {
        Set<JobRequest> jobRequests = JobManager.instance().getAllJobRequestsForTag(SyncMasterDataJOB.TAG);
        if (!jobRequests.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        new JobRequest.Builder(SyncMasterDataJOB.TAG)
              .setPeriodic(MIN_INTERVAL, MIN_FLEX)
               .build()
                .schedule();
    }


}
```

But the Problem is My onRunJob() method is never called. I am new to Android JOBS. Can anyone tell me where i am doing wrong?

I am Taking reference from [here](https://github.com/evernote/android-job)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Job creator class ->

```
public class CreateJob implements JobCreator {

    private Context context;

    public CreateJob(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    //  Here we have to register each of the jobs...
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Job create(@NonNull String tag) {
        switch (tag) {
            case CurrentWeatherUpdateJob.TAG:
                return new CurrentWeatherUpdateJob();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

this is where i am registering my JobCreator.

```
//  To use StartingPoint Anywhere in our app
//  else you have to Instantiate StartingPoint inside every Activities on create...
public class StartingPoint extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        //  Create Job is a class that registers all the Jobs...
        JobManager.create(this).addJobCreator(new CreateJob(getApplicationContext()));

    }
}
```

This is your Jobs Subclass ->

```
public class CurrentWeatherUpdateJob extends Job {

    public static final String TAG = "CurrentWeatherUpdateJob";

    //  Update Weather Data every 15 Minutes...
    private static final int CURRENTWEATHERUPDATE_TIMEINTERVAL = 15 * 60 * 1000;

    //  Interface that provides Data...
    private ApiInterface service;

    //  For Celcius - metric / Kelvin - imperial
    private String UnitType = "metric";

    public CurrentWeatherUpdateJob() {
        service = APIClient.getRetrofit_Weather().create(ApiInterface.class);
    }

    private static void ScheduleJobEvery15Minutes() {
        //  Scheduling Job After every 15 minutes...
        new JobRequest.Builder(TAG)
                .setPeriodic(CURRENTWEATHERUPDATE_TIMEINTERVAL)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobRequest.NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .setRequirementsEnforced(true)
                .setUpdateCurrent(true)
                .build()
                .schedule();
    }

    // implement your onRunJob method here
}
```

Call your ScheduleJobEvery15Minutes() method from your activity you want.

Comment: When I removed Felx interval it is working fine for me. Thanks brother

Comment: you'r welcome, felix interval stands for running the Job after the provided felix interval. so, if you set felix interval of 5 min and period as 15 min, your job will start after 5 min and will run every 15 min. removing it will run your job immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is not in your code, but in the Setting up of the Period of the Job. evernote only works with periodic Job >=15 Min, while you are using 1 minute as period for running the Job. see the Documentation of evenote-job as it's based on Job-scheduler, which has the same constraint for running periodic job.

```
private void schedulePeriodicJob() {
    int jobId = new JobRequest.Builder(DemoSyncJob.TAG)
            .setPeriodic(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15), TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5))
            .build()
            .schedule();
}
```

this is the code that they put on their Library Documentation. Please check this out. ->

**Why can't an interval be smaller than 15 minutes for periodic jobs?** This library is a subset of 3 different APIs. Since Android Nougat the minimum interval of periodic jobs is 15 minutes. Although pre Nougat devices support smaller intervals, the least common was chosen as minimum for this library so that periodic jobs run with the same frequency on all devices.

The JobScheduler with Android Nougat allows setting a smaller interval, but the value is silently adjusted and a warning is being logged. This library throws an exception instead, so that misbehaving jobs are caught early. You can read more about it here.

this is the code that works for me ->

where //  Update Weather Data every 15 Minutes...

```
private static final int CURRENTWEATHERUPDATE_TIMEINTERVAL = 15 * 60 * 1000;

  private static void ScheduleJobEvery15Minutes() {
        //  Scheduling Job After every 15 minutes...
        new JobRequest.Builder(TAG)
                .setPeriodic(CURRENTWEATHERUPDATE_TIMEINTERVAL)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobRequest.NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .setRequirementsEnforced(true)
                .setUpdateCurrent(true)
                .build()
                .schedule();
    }
```

**EDIT ->** Also check your Jobcreator class, you are returning null value like this,

```
public class CreatingJob implements JobCreator {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Job create(@NonNull String tag) {
        switch (tag) {
            case SyncMasterDataJOB.TAG:
                return new SyncMasterDataJOB();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

change your code to this ->

```
public class CreatingJob implements JobCreator {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public Job create(@NonNull String tag) {
            switch (tag) {
                case SyncMasterDataJOB.TAG:
                    return new SyncMasterDataJOB();
                case default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: But i am using the same as shown in Documentation I have used .setPeriodic(MIN_INTERVAL, MIN_FLEX) which is equivalent to  .setPeriodic(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15), TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5))

Comment: No you are using 60 seconds as time interval, which is 1 minute.

Comment: MIN_INTERVAL =TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15)
MIN_FLEX=TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5)
These are static variables in evernote library

Comment: i dont use that variables min and max

Comment: check your file explorer inside your data/data/package name of your app and there will be a db folder which will have pending JOBs for the evenote-job that you set, check that if there is any pending job there or not.

Comment: @ShashwatGupta, check out the function that i have written check if that works for you or not, also remove   
                 .setRequiredNetworkType(JobRequest.NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .setRequirementsEnforced(true) if not neccessary for your application.

Comment: let me check this and let you know

Comment: it is not finding any CURRENTWEATHERUPDATE_TIMEINTERVAL?

Comment: bro that's the Interval timing, see the code that  i have changed.

Comment: no bro its not working for taking default case it is showing me unexpected token

Comment: I have changed your jobcreator class, see if that helps.

Comment: case should not be there in Java for default case we use only default

Comment: let me put my code and you just copy/paste it, if that works.